# Upload image with PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, image

i'm tring to store to my Database an image that comes from an Android application.

To save the image in my db (in a column BLOB) i use the following code.

```
$enc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($enc));
```

Then i pass $image to the query to insert into the database. Now, i would like also to store the image as .jpeg into a folder called "avatars". I tried this code.

```
move_uploaded_file($enc, "avatars/img.jpeg");
```

In avatars folder i see "img.jpeg" but when i try to open it, Altervista say me that the image contains errors and can't be open. How can i solve?

Comment: Are you sure it's a jpg? How do you send it?

Comment: Is the blob throwing the error but not the image? What about storing the location of the image rather than the blob? Also see ^, if not `jpg` that could cause issues.

Comment: check the type of the image your uploading. or else just use the same name of the image uploaded to store in the folder `avatars` using `$_FILES['image']['name']`.

Comment: Trust me when I say this, don't use blob to store an image in your database, I spent 1 month trying to use BLOB with no luck. Use @chris85 method. Make a folder in the directory of your project in localhost named "Avatars", then change your column "image" or "imageLocation" from BLOB to varchar, when you upload, send the image to that new folder and simply store it as "Images/blablah.jpg" in your database, much easier